# Graph url in FB.api

Tags: url, facebook-graph-api, http-post

I'm trying to pass a friend's name and image to post to a user's wall. But I'm hung up on the javascript to make this possible. Go ahead and assume key to be the facebook friend's user id and name to be the name (that part works actually). Not sure on the javascript or if this is possible.

```
function postMeet(key, name)
{
        var params = {};
        params['message'] = 'Message';
        params['name'] = name;
        params['description'] = 'Description';
        params['link'] = 'https://graph.facebook.com/{key}';
        params['picture'] = 'https://graph.facebook.com/{key}/picture?type=square';
        params['caption'] = 'Caption';

        FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', params, function(response) {
           if (!response || response.error) {
           alert('Error occured');
           } else {
           alert('Published to stream - you might want to delete it now!');
           }
           });          
}
```

Comment: It works with the following changes, however I still can't get the picture to work. I think it has something with that being the image source and not the actual image:
    var linkstring='https://www.facebook.com/' + key;
    var pic = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + key + '/picture';
        
            var params = {};
            params['message'] = 'Message';
            params['name'] = 'name';
            params['description'] = 'Description';
            params['link'] = linkstring;
            params['picture'] = picstring;
            params['caption'] = 'Caption';